# If I want to click the word in html then this word will changing like translate

Tags: javascript, html

If I want to click the word in html then this word will changing like translate.

```
<p class="paragraph article__item" id="p4">
Hallo World, I need help. </p>
```

```js
var find = ["Hello","World“,"I"];
var replace = [„Hallo“, „Welt“,'Ich']; 

(function() {

    var myVar;
    var distance;
    var numberOfWords = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    var calculateClick;

    $("p").each(function(i, p) {
      var words = $(p).text();

      $(p).html("");
      $(words.split(" ")).each(function(j, word) {
        var span = $("<span id='element" + numberOfWords + "'></span>");
        var a = span.html(word);
        alert(a.html);
        numberOfWords++;
        $(p).append(span).append("&nbsp;");
      });
    });

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) {

      $('#element' + i).on("click", function() {
          $(this).attr('style', 'color:green;');
          $(this).text().css("color", "");
        }



        $(this).attr('style', 'color:purple;'); $(this).text().css("color", "");


        for (j = 0; j < numberOfWords; j++) {
          if ($('#element' + j).length) {


            if ($(this).text() == $('#element' + j).text()) {
              var findWord = ($(this));
              $('#element' + j).attr("style", "")
              $('#element' + j).attr('class', 'shake');




            }
          }
        }

      })
  };


})();
```

but I don't know how to replace the word (`Hello` to `Hallo`) when I click in html.

**Example:**

```
var find = ["Hello","World“,"I"]; 
var to = ["Hallo", "Welt", "Ich"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's all you'd need to do:

```
$("#p4").click(function() {
    $("#p4").html = "Hello World, I need help.";
});
```

(I'm using jQuery because I can see you're already using it)